# Where/when to implement some COUNT() statements in my MVC application

Tags: php, database, oop, datamapper

Ok so I have my `CustomerMapper` mapping my `Customer` domain object perfectly but today I was in the middle of some business logic in one of my domain objects which uses my `Customer` object and I realized I needed to have some sort of

```
if( $customer->getNumActiveOrders() > self::MAX_NUM_ORDERS )
```

Currently my `Customer` object does not have a `$numActiveOrders` property so I would have to fetch the number of active orders for this customer only when the `getNumActiveOrders()` method is called.

The confusion is how do I go about doing this without having any database logic in my `Customer` domain object? Maybe inject a DAO into my `Customer` object on creation and let it stop database logic leaking into my domain object? I do not really like the idea of having anything database related in my domain objects though so I am unsure about that one.

Maybe I should have a `$numActiveOrders` property in my object and just set it when my DataMapper fetches the customer? I do not think I will need this value too much, maybe 3 times (if even) in the whole application so I do not want to be doing an extra query every time I create a `Customer`

How do people do this sort of task efficiently and without leaking database logic into domain objects?

Thanks.

Comment: How about a CustomerLogic class? Then you could pass `customer` to the logic class and your call would look something like: `CustomerLogic.GetNumberOfActiveOrders(customer)`. (That's C#. I'm not familiar with PHP.)

Comment: @BobHorn, that solution would be bad in all languages. Or are you saying that C# promotes stupid practices? On related note: [read this](https://twitter.com/KentBeck/status/325995256409640962).

Comment: @tereško No need to be rude. We'd all be better off helping each other instead of just complaining about a solution. If you have a better idea, please share it.